# Parsing urls containing specific filetypes in a mediawiki dump

Tags: mediawiki, large-files

I've a large .xml file (about 500mb) which is a dump of site based on mediawiki.

My goal is to find all url links, which contain image filename extensions. Then group links by second level domain and export result containing only links in above order.

Example: there're many links beginning with domain.com/*.png, host.com/*.png and image.com/*.png. Grouping them in separate files divided by specific second level domain with it's links - that's a final result.

Comment: Ok, you described what you want, what is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to use grep but I can group links as written above

Answer (score 0):

So you want to parse the links in the wikitext. Writing a [MediaWiki parser](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) is a pain, so you should use an existing parser.

The easiest way (easiest but not easy) is probably to [import your dump](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing) into a MediaWiki install and rebuild some tables id needed, then export the externallinks table.